# The build command is not replacing the env variables on my React app created with Vite

Tags: reactjs, docker-compose, dockerfile, environment-variables, vite

I create my React application using Vite, and it is working well on development (`npm run dev`). but when I run `npm run build` in my container or localy, it is not replacing the environment variable by static values as it should happen acordinly with the documentation (https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#production-replacement).

This is how the code is:

```js
await fetch(`${import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL}/users`, {
        headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
    });
```

This is the replacement

```
await fetch(`${{}.VITE_API_URL}/users`,{headers:{Authorization:`Bearer ${e}`}})
```

It only works if I have the `.env.production` file, but I want to use the environment variables.